# First steps in moving a CSV to a MySQL relational database. CSV structure != MySQL structure

Tags: mysql, csv, join

I have a CSV that is in the following format:

```
Module, Topic, Sub-topic
```

It needs to be able to be imported into a MySQL database that has the following format:

```
CREATE TABLE `modules` (
  `id` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `module` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `module_ref_idx` (`module`),
  CONSTRAINT `module` FOREIGN KEY (`module`) REFERENCES `modules` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=648 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `subtopics` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `topic` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `topic_idx` (`topic`),
  CONSTRAINT `topic` FOREIGN KEY (`topic`) REFERENCES `topics` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I know I'm able to insert the data from the CSV file to MySQL and keep the data integrity, but I'm not sure how.  The data from the CSV needs to be put in the 'name' fields in each table, while keeping the relationship of data in tact.

I'm playing in Workbench right now and can't get it right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So somehow you want use 3 columns to populate 11?

Comment: I want the data from the original data set to populate the name fields in each of the 3 tables while keeping the relationships in tact

Comment: Why is there a `module  varchar(30)` in the `topics` table, also what happens to the `active` field ?

Comment: `module` in `topics` is the reference for the `modules` table.  It is the `id` in the `modules` table

Comment: Can we assume that a module has multiple topics, a topic has multiple subtopics and the CSV contains all the subtopics with their corresponding topic and module?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table to load the csv (a TEMPORARY one can be used too)

```
CREATE TABLE `tmp_subtopics` (
    `module` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `topic` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `subtopic` VARCHAR(50) NULL
)
```

Load the csv (you might need additional options for encoding, field names.. etc)

```
 LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE tmp_subtopics
```

Insert the modules

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO modules (name)
 SELECT DISTINCT module FROM tmp_subtopics
```

Insert the topics

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO topics (name,module)
SELECT DISTINCT
    tmp.topic,
    m.id
FROM tmp_subtopics tmp
JOIN modules m ON m.name = tmp.module
```

Insert the subtopics

```
INSERT INTO subtopics (name,topic)
SELECT
    tmp.subtopic,
    t.id
FROM tmp_subtopics tmp
JOIN topics t ON t.name = tmp.topic
```

Also:

`UNIQUE KEY id (id)` is redundant, you should probably remove it.

The `module` field in the `topics` table should be a `INT` not `VARCHAR`.